# how to create a vhd on windows 7 64 bit and use it with virtual box

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, virtual, virtualbox, vhd

after playing with virtual hard drive in windows 7 (first time) this is a recap on how you do it in case you are a newbie. I use two steps: disk2vhd.exe and then oracle VM
I used disk2vhd(from system internals) to convert the physical PC to a virtual Hard Drive (VHD) 
 when running disk2vhd.exe you can choose what drive you want to have, I did checked my c:\ and the system reserved (there is one more PQService drive which I did not select, but so far am working fine as of dec 12,2013) 
a note: if you don't select/check the system reserved drive the VHD won't work under virtual box).
once the disk2vhd.exe finished I started my oracle VM virtual box and click new button, a wizard poped; enter the name(myPC), type(Microsoft windows), version(windows 7 64bit),Memory size (at least 4096mb) ,Hard Drive - select "use an existing virtual hard drive file" select the vhd image created by disk2vhd.exe, continue and finish the wizard... once the VM is created here is the tricky part, click the setting button and go to storage  under storage tree add your VHD  to the controller IDE and under attributes- Hard disk: IDE primary master (at this point was able to start my VM. it did run couple check disks but, started fine. 
Please feel free to add to this post if I missed something important....thanks.
good luck!